# Platform Builder for WinCE 7.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm using Windows XP 32-bit OS. I installed `Visual Studio 2008` initially. Then, I installed `WinCE 7.0 Evaluation version`. Now, when I check for Platform Builder in Visual Studio, there is no such tool. I haven't installed `VS SP1`. Is it anything to do with that? But, isn't it integrated with WinCE 7.0? I checked out in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winembplatdev/thread/a0149634-4aec-41ab-905c-ebaf68db5f86/) and tried to find `PB.msi` file in WinCE directory. But, couldn't find that also. There is no Platform Builder option in `'Tools'` menu. And, also not listed in `Add-In`s.

Kindly guide me what should I do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it right & would like to share it as an answer. The problem was that I didn't install Visual Studio SP1. Though Platform Builder comes along with WinCE installation, it is a plug-in for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 only. I previously didn't understand this connectivity, hence made this mistake of not installing the Service Pack 1. The order of installation is,

1. Visual Studio 2008 Professional
2. [Visual Studio SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=10986)
3. [WinCE 7.0 Evaluation Version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19004)

Thanks!